# active_model_serializer + devise + rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, active-model-serializers

I was struggling with `undefined method 'authenticate' for nil:NilClass` for my requests using the serializer (Rspec).

**api/users_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #show" do
    context "with valid credentials" do
      let!(:application) { create(:doorkeeper_application) } # OAuth application
      let!(:user)        { create(:user) }
      let!(:token)       { create(:doorkeeper_access_token, application_id: application.id, resource_owner_id: user.id) }
      before do
        allow(controller).to receive(:doorkeeper_token) {token}
      end

      context 'and valid request' do
        before(:each) do
          get :show, format: :json
          @json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        end

        it "returns the user with 'id'" do
          expect(@json["id"]).to_not be_nil
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**serializers/user_serializer.rb**

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :uid, :name, :email
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I needed was to add `serialization_scope :view_context` to my `ApplicationController` but I only discovered it when watching the amazing Railcast about the gem: http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast

## Edited

Don't use active_model_serializer > 0.9.x otherwise it will break in production.
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/commit/0d31e72d2211b6bf7f0b0420139c4b370d6e986e
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/139

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me in my Rails 4.2.1 project. Weird thing is that I didn't need to set this in my Rails 5 project. :/